# Reselect selectors and Redux Store with frequently changing properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, redux, reselect

I have a store that looks like the following:

- allItems

  - item1: {uivalue1: 1, uivalue2: 2, position: {x, y}}
  - ...
- selectedItemsKeys: ['item1', 'item2']

Some of the UI components that I have need only render when ui values change and ignore position data that changes frequently but does not affect those UI components.

The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to create a selector that would not recalculate its results whenever position values change on the items.

```
// This is a basic selector that will always return new reference and values
const getSelectedItems = (state) =>
    getAllItems(state).subset(getSelectedItemsKeys(state));

// This is how I'd usually cache the result with `reselect` except this
// would not work since `getAllItems` will be changing frequently when
// position data changes inside one of the items.
const  getSelectedItems = createSelector(
  getAllItems,
  getSelectedItemsKeys,
  (allItems, selectedKeys) => allItems.subset(selectedKeys)
);
```

The structure for `allItems` is potentially out of my control so I would like a solution that does not involve changing where that position data is stored. Any thoughts on ways to solve this?

I've tried to work with `re-reselect` but it looks like it would still recalculate if one of the input selectors values change regardless if the cache key stayed the same or not. This is what I tried:

```
// I thought this might work, but I might be mis-understanding how re-reselect works.
// This still recalculates even though the cache keys do not change and they are in the
// cache.
const getSelectedItems = createCachedSelector(
    getAllItems,
    getSelectedItemsKeys,
    (allItems, selectedKeys) => allItems.subset(selectedKeys)
)(
    (state) => `keys-${state.selectedItemsKeys.join(':')}`
);
```

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding something about how React works, or I am misunderstanding your question. Wouldn't you want the selector to recompute it's value if any of the inputs change? If `allItems` is a new array then React necessarily needs to be passed the new array reference so it can reconcile the difference and rerender. If individual elements haven't updated (i.e. their mapped key hasn't changed) then React will bail on rerendering them.

Comment: If you want your component to prevent creating jsx and skip React virtual dom compare then you have to take out position values from allItems, maybe something like `positions: {item1:{x,y}}`. Drew is correct that React won't repaint if components generate the same jsx (it will because you don't use position in generated jsx) but when you do something like `onClick={()=>'new ref to onClick'}` then it will repaint so to prevent that you should use the useCallback hook.

Comment: I am not familiar with `Object.prototype.subset`, is allItems not a plain object and what does subset return (array, object, ...)?